# How can we pass header through Alamofire in swift2 ios8

Tags: header, alamofire

how i can pass Headers with Alamofire in ios8. in AFNetworking we use to do like this`[manager.requestSerializer setValue:struseraccessToken forHTTPHeaderField:@"b82043d448c72371"];`
same way how i can do in Alamofire 3.2.0 .